# How can I store and interact with multiple individual python sessions in c++?

Tags: python, c++

Within my c++ program, I have a class called "pEngine" that is supposed to handle interaction between my program and a python session. There can be any number of these pEngines and each one needs to be working individually since during their initialization they each execute a different python script (unknown till run time).

Currently I have each script defining a main function that takes a single variable, the payload, and depending on the script produces a different output which my program pipes back. The pEngine is then deleted. For a single pEngine my code works great allowing me to preload data in the script for the function, then call it later when needed.

My problem is that since it closes its session, all other pEngines are effected. I cannot load multiple scripts into the same session since they all have have the same prototype for their main function. What I was looking for was a way to have a python session instance object that is separate and individual so I could run commands against it.

My pEngine.h

```
#include <cstring>
#include "Engine.h"
#include "/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h"

#ifndef PENGINE_H
#define PENGINE_H

class pEngine : public Engine
{
public:
    pEngine();
    ~pEngine();

    std::string execute(const std::string& cmd);         
    int setwd(const std::string& dir);
    int source(const std::string& script);

    std::string main(const std::string& payload);
private:
        PyObject *pModule;
        PyObject *stdOut;
};

#endif /* PENGINE_H */
```

My pEngine.cpp

```
#include "pEngine.h"

pEngine::pEngine()
{
    /* Start a python session and create a class to capture the standard out 
     text. Define it as the standard out location and run this code in the 
     session. Then store a pointer to this python object to extract returned
     values. */
    Py_Initialize();
    pModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__"); //create main module
    std::stringstream pythonOutputs;
    pythonOutputs << "import sys" << "\n"
                  << "class CatchStdOut:" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "def __init__(self):" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "\t" << "self.value = ''" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "def write(self, txt):" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "\t" << "self.value += txt" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "def clear(self):" << "\n"
                  << "\t" << "\t" << "self.value = ''" << "\n"
                  << "StdOut = CatchStdOut()" << "\n"
                  << "sys.stdout = StdOut";
    PyRun_SimpleString((pythonOutputs.str()).c_str());
    stdOut = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"StdOut");
}

pEngine::~pEngine(){
    Py_Finalize();
}

std::string pEngine::execute(const std::string& cmd)
{   
    /* Place cmd in try except statement to protect against unknown errors. */
    std::stringstream pString;
    pString << "program_status = 200" << "\n"
            << "StdOut.clear()" << "\n"
            << "try:" << "\n"
            << "\t" << cmd << "\n"
            << "except Exception as e:" << "\n"
            << "\t" << "program_status = 400" << "\n"
            << "\t" << "print(e)";

    /* Run Command against the interpreter and store returned answer. */
    PyRun_SimpleString( (pString.str()).c_str() );
    PyErr_Print(); //make python print

    //returned payload
    std::string RPL = 
        PyString_AsString(PyObject_GetAttrString(stdOut,"value"));


    /* Clear the payload from the capture object and run a command to fill in
     the status. */
    std::stringstream statusCollector;
    statusCollector << "StdOut.clear()\n"
                    << "print program_status";

    /* Run command and extract status. */
    PyRun_SimpleString( (statusCollector.str()).c_str() );
    PyErr_Print();

    //status
    std::string PST = 
        PyString_AsString(PyObject_GetAttrString(stdOut,"value"));

    if (!RPL.empty() && RPL[RPL.length()-1] == '\n') RPL.erase(RPL.length()-1);
    if (!PST.empty() && PST[PST.length()-1] == '\n') PST.erase(PST.length()-1);

    /* Set Program status and return the payload from the python session. */
    program_status = std::stoi( PST );
    return RPL;
}

std::string pEngine::main(const std::string& payload)
{
    std::string returned = execute( "print main("+toEscapedString(payload)+")");
    Py_Finalize();
    if( program_status != 200 ) status = Engine::ENG_EXECUTE_ERROR;
    return returned;
}

int pEngine::setwd(const std::string& dir)
{
    std::string pString = "import os\n\tos.chdir(" + toEscapedString(dir) + ")";
    execute( pString );
    if( program_status != 200 ) status = Engine::ENG_SESSION_ERROR;
    return status;
}

int pEngine::source(const std::string& script)
{    
    std::string pString = "execfile(" + toEscapedString(script) + ")";
    execute( pString );
    if( program_status != 200 ) status = Engine::ENG_SESSION_ERROR;
    return status;
}
```

Comment: The way I did this was to spawn the python script as a sub-process, and communicate with it via its stdin and stdout streams (or, alternatively, by having the Python process open a TCP connection back to the C++ parent process).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea, I'll give it a go :)